# Open my Chrome devtools extension from browser context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to add a context menu item to Chrome that will open my custom devtools extension panel, but I cannot find any information out there on how to do this. Is this just not allowed? The flow is simple:

- Right click on page, select 'Open MyExtension'
- Open developer tools with MyExtension panel open

Comment: Like this? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation wOxxOm.  That's what I thought, but wasn't sure if I just wasn't googling the proper questions.

Comment: Thanks Will - that's the basic idea of what I'm trying to do, but since my extension is a devtools extension, the context menu that I'd add would be pointless.